# How get all people with the same height in a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have this list of dictionaries:

```
data = [{"nome": "joao",    "idade": "16", "altura": "167"},
        {"nome": "Gabriel", "idade": "12", "altura": "167"},
        {"nome": "Rodrigo", "idade": "14", "altura": "170"},
        {"nome": "Filipe",  "idade": "21", "altura": "167"}]
```

And what I need to return is something like this:

```
{167: 3, 170: 1}
```

It seems so easy, and it must exists something to do it in one step, but I just can't do it (I must not use any kind of import).
Does anyone know how?

Comment: `Counter(i["altura"] for i in data)` Imports: [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

Answer (score 2):

```py
from collections import Counter
result = Counter(d["altura"] for d in data)
print(result)
# result: Counter({'167': 3, '170': 1})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
heights = {}
for i in data:
    if i["altura"] in heights:
        heights[i["altura"]] += 1
    else:
        heights[i["altura"]] = 1

print(heights)
```

Comment: Perfect, the only thing I changed is that I did it in one line only to do some cleaning, the complexity is good and it works just fine

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is

```
obj = [itm["altura"] for itm in data]
{key: obj.count(key) for key in set(obj)}
```

Comment: The algorithm works, but its asymptotic complexity is way to high, if would run this on my csv data it would took at least 1 full minute, but it is undoubtedly working